# ESP32-C3 GPIO glitch filter error 'gpio_new_pin_glitch_filter' was not declared in this scope (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm trying to build a small device using the ESP32-C3 running Arduino core.

From the documentation it appears the ESP32's have built-in hardware 'glitch filters' which I understand to filter out bounce usually associated with things like physical switches and handled via 'debounce' code.  I can see this would be particularly useful when using that input as an interrupt or wakeup source as a software filter wouldn't be effective in that scenario.

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32c3/api-reference/peripherals/gpio.html#gpio-glitch-filter

When trying to use this and built my project:

```
gpio_new_pin_glitch_filter(GPIO_PIN);
```

I get the error:

```
'gpio_new_pin_glitch_filter' was not declared in this scope
```

It looks like this type of functionality is available on most ESP32 devices.  All I can think is that Arduino platform for ESP32 does not include handlers for this functionality.  If that's the case is there a way I can still leverage this feature in my Arduino project?

Answer (score 1):

The function `gpio_new_pin_glitch_filter()` appears to have been added to ESP-IDF version 5.1. At the time this question was asked the current version of the Arduino framework was [v2.0.14](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/releases/tag/2.0.14) which is based on ESP-IDF v4.4.6. This function wasn't available in that version of ESP-IDF and therefore won't be available to Arduino programs using this version of the framework.

If you want to call `gpio_new_pin_glitch_filter()` from your Arduino program, you'll need to use a version of the Arduino framework that's built on a version of ESP-IDF that includes the function. That doesn't exist yet. Your options would be to back port [`gpio_new_pin_glitch_filter()`](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/b4268c874a4/components/driver/gpio/include/driver/gpio_filter.h) to ESP-IDF v4.4.6 or to rewrite your application to directly run on ESP-IDF 5.1 rather than the Arduino framework.